# Distribution Function how can we find c such that F(c) = 1/2

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let X be a random variable on some probability space ($\Omega$,S,P) Assume that F(x) is the Distribution function of X.

I know that DF F(x) is monotonically increasing and right continuous between [0,1], but how can point out that for specific x, we can get certain F(x) =1/2.
For example, exists c$\in$ R such that F(c)$\geq$ 1/2 and F(c-) $\leq$ 1/2

Answer (score 1):

In general, the DF of a random variable $X$ is non-decreasing and right-continuous.

So, there may be infinitely many $x$'s for which $F(x) = 1/2$ (if $F$ is flat), or exactly one, or none at all (if $F$ jumps). It all depends on the specifics of $F$.

If you have an explicit expression for F and it is increasing (i.e. strictly) on some domain, then you may invert the expression $y = F(x)$ and write $x$ in terms of $y$, i.e. $x = F^{-1}(y)$.

Then, $x = F^{-1}(1/2)$ will give you what you want.